# Complex solution for, $\ln(x)+\ln(-x)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find the complex solution for the equation, $\ln(x)+\ln(-x)=0$

**Solution:**

$1^{st}$ Approach,
$${\ln(x)+\ln(-x)=0\\
\Rightarrow \ln(x)+\ln(i^2x)=0\\
\Rightarrow \ln(x)+2\ln(\pm i)+\ln(x)=0\\
\Rightarrow \ln(x)=-\ln(\pm i)=\ln(\mp i)\\
\Rightarrow x=\pm i} \text{where $i$ is $\sqrt {-1}$}$$

$2^{nd}$ Approach,

$$ {\ln(x)+\ln(-x)=0\\
\Rightarrow \ln(i^2x^2)=0\\
\Rightarrow i^2x^2=1\\
\Rightarrow x^2=i^{-2}=-1\\
\Rightarrow x= \pm i}\ \text{where $i$ is $\sqrt {-1}$}$$

> How can I prove that an equation has only two solutions?

Comment: Define $\ln x$ and prove that $\ln (a^{2}b)=2\ln a +\ln b$.

Comment: No branch of logarithm in the complex plane satisfies $\log (ab)=\log a+\log b$. You cannot blindly apply  what you have learnt about logarithms, powers, etc for positive numbers to complex numbers.

Comment: @geetha290krm are you sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log z = \log |z| + i \arg(z) + 2\pi i k, \quad k \in \mathbb Z,$$ where $\arg(z) = \arctan \frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}$ is the argument of $z$.  Then $$0 = \log z + \log(-z) = 2 \log |z| + i (\arg(z) + \arg(-z)) + 4\pi i k,$$ assuming we pick the same branch for $\log z$ and $\log(-z)$.
Hence we require $\log|z| = 0$ or $|z| = 1$.  Let $z = e^{i\theta}$ so that $\arg(z) = \theta$, $\arg(-z) = \theta + \pi$.  Then
$$\arg(z) + \arg(-z) + 4\pi k = 2\theta + \pi + 4\pi k = \left(\frac{2\theta}{\pi} + 1 + 4k\right)\pi.$$  We need this to be an integer multiple of $2\pi$, hence $$\frac{2\theta}{\pi} + 1 = 2m$$ for some integer $m$.  Therefore,
$$\theta = \frac{(2m-1)}{2}\pi$$
and $$z = e^{i\theta} = e^{m\pi i} e^{-\pi i/2} = \pm i.$$